# Fixed positioned element bounces up and down on scrolling in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fixed

I got this code: http://kod.djpw.cz/xodb-

And the fixed element bounces up and down on scrolling. This actually happens only in IE.
I need to have that blurred background but I guess it makes no difference in this case.

Bouncing stops when I remove: `margin: 0px;` from `body`

Actually I would rather have margin specified like this: `*{margin: 0px;}` if its possible.

But I really need it to be there, otherwise it actually makes margin on top and left side.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: its not clear what you are asking for? could you make it more clear.

Comment: If you open this site : [link](http://kod.djpw.cz/xodb-) and start scrolling, the blue fixed element will move up (5px I guess) if you start scrolling down and down if scroll up. This however only happens in Internet Explorer!

Comment: the box does not move, its is set to position: fixed;, the page moves behind it?

Comment: But it moves on my browser...

Comment: not sure why, which version of ie are u using

Comment: so do I, so not sure why it does this?

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't have a clue why it would do that, it is fixed for me.

Comment: I use IE version: 11.0.9600.17107

Comment: same version as me, I can only think that some extension on your IE may cause this?

Comment: video here: [link](http://youtu.be/aQKiUm98kBk)

Answer (score 0):

Set that element z-index to 99 and try if it works....

e.g:

```
box{ position: fixed; z-index: 99; }
```

Comment: It doesnt do anything. Btw, there was originally: position: fixed; z-index: 101;, I dont think that would do any better with z-index right below 100..